# can we convert layered architecture project to MVC project in .net 4.1?

Tags: .net

i developed the .net project in layered architecture in vs studio 4.1, is that possible to convert to MVC project, or we have to start from scratch
if it can be done there is any way to change normal html5  to Razer ?.

**i have developed the project in layered architecture in asp.net ,i used DAL and BAL with stored procedures , so i have to convert this project to MVC , is tat possible by doing some modification or i have to develop everything new in MVC**

Comment: what?? your question is completely unclear.

Comment: What you're asking doesn't make a lot of sense.  If you have portable de-coupled .NET code, an MVC project can reference that code just like any other project can.  What does this have to do with HTML5 and Razor syntax?  You don't have to "convert HTML5 to Razor", you can use HTML in your MVC views.

Comment: Depends on what in your meaning is "layered architecture", "vs studio 4.1", "razer" and what kind of project you have developed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others pointed, there is no such thing as VS 4.1. 
Secondly, I think I can clear up the confusion. You already have an N-Tier architecture solution but you are wanting to use MVC. Well, if your separation of concerns are very well done (i.e a business logic has no dependencies on any UI stuff etc... and your DAL is separated) then you should be good and the only thing you need to do is develop the MVC (UI) side of things and "map" or integrate them into your business logic/services layer.

If there is tight coupling, then you will have problems, still not the end of the world but again, depends if you have your business logic/services/middle tier and DAL separated correctly to be able to do the replacement of your UI with little or no pain.

Comment: thank you for response ,but actually i am  having separate DAL,BAL,configured with SP, so is that possible to integrate all in MVC with new UI, then which will act as the model ,what i have to configure in controller?

Comment: yes it is possible but you need to understand what MVC and how it works. MVC is Model View and Controller. your controller would be the one to call your BAL and then the data would be used to for example create the model and bind to the view. There is no magic way of making it work automatically or at ease. you will be redeveloping just the UI layer (the MVC layer)

Comment: thank you so much ,definitely your points will be useful for me

Comment: you are well, feel free to upvote my answer or mark as answer if you prefer.